# Debugging my app

Tags: android, debugging

I noticed that randomly my phone restarts. I am not sure if this is because of my app (which I recently developed) or because of a Android 4.3 bug with with the Nexus 4. I am terribly sorry if this is the wrong forum. Any advice on how I can exactly pinpoint the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your phone for a while without your app? If the problem doesn't occur you can then work on investigating the app.